# Nextjs server error : "could not find the module"

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Next version: 13.4.12
Node version: 18.17.0

When I create a next app with "npx create-next-app@latest" and npm run dev immediately after creating it, I am getting the following error.

**Server Error
Error: Could not find the module "C:\Users\Kerem\Desktopudb-next\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\app-router.js#default" in the React Client Manifest. This is probably a bug in the React Server Components bundler.
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.**

You can also check the image.[image: error image]

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/50243) seems related? may be try a different version?

Comment: I tried everything mentioned under that issue but didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Resolved.

As seen in the attached photo, the path appears to be "..../Desktopudb/...". My app's name is "udb," located on my desktop. However, the absence of "/" between them causes this issue. Changing my app directory's name to "-udb" eliminates the problem.